# Resize PopUp video maintaining the aspect ratio in flex

Tags: actionscript, flex4, popup, resize, aspect-ratio

i have a TitleWindow popup which opens a videoDisplay to play a video when i click on a thumb.What i want is my popup to resize and the video inside it but to maintain its original aspect ratio and not stretch...

any ideas?

Thanks a lot! Here is my popUp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           close="CloseWindow(event)" >
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;
        import mx.events.ResizeEvent;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;


        [Bindable]public var mediaServerUrl:String;
        [Bindable]public var videoFolder:String;
        [Bindable]public var filename:String;
        [Bindable]public var comments:String;


        private var ns:NetStream;
        private var nc:NetConnection;
        private var video:Video;
        private var meta:Object;

        private function ns_onMetaData(item:Object):void {
            trace("meta");
            meta = item;
            // Resize Video object to same size as meta data.
            video.width = item.width;
            video.height = item.height;
            // Resize UIComponent to same size as Video object.
            myVid.width = video.width;
            myVid.height = video.height;

        }

        private function fetch_rec():void {
            var nsClient:Object = {};
            nsClient.onMetaData = ns_onMetaData;


            nc = new NetConnection();
            nc.connect(null);
            ns = new NetStream(nc);
            ns.client = nsClient;

            video = new Video(myVid.width,myVid.height);
            video.attachNetStream(ns);
            video.smoothing=true;
            myVid.addChild(video);
            ns.play(mediaServerUrl+"/"+videoFolder+"/"+filename+".flv");

        }

        protected function CloseWindow(event:CloseEvent):void
        {
            ns.close();
            nc.close();
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:VideoDisplay id="myVid" visible="true" x="0" bottom="50" width="100%" height="100%"
                 maintainAspectRatio="true"
                 autoPlay="true" 
                 creationComplete="fetch_rec()"
                 playheadUpdate="progBar.setProgress(myVid.playheadTime,myVid.totalTime)"/>

<mx:ProgressBar id="progBar" left="10" right="10" bottom="60" height="10" label="" mode="manual"/>
<s:Label x="10" bottom="30" text="Σχόλια:"/>

<s:Label x="10" bottom="10" text="{comments}"/></s:TitleWindow>
```

to call this popup i do:

```
 protected function launchPopUp(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(list.selectedItem){
                win = new ViewVideoPopUp();
                win.width = this.width;
                win.height = this.height;

                //give what is needed to play the video selected
                win.videoFolder = videoFolder;              // the video's folder name
                win.mediaServerUrl = mediaServerUrl;        // the media server url
                win.filename = list.selectedItem.filename;  // the file to be played
                win.comments = list.selectedItem.comments;  // the comments left for that
                win.title = list.selectedItem.name+" στις "+list.selectedItem.date; //title of the window

                this.addEventListener(ResizeEvent.RESIZE, window_resize);
                PopUpManager.addPopUp(win,this,true);
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(win);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (12/15):
OK, I tried your code and added a method to force the aspect ratio of the video based on the aspect ratio of the parent container.  I put a HGroup around the VideoDisplay component, and used that to figure out how the video should be sized. It also centers the video in the popup if the window and video are different sizes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           close="CloseWindow(event)" autoLayout="true">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;
        import mx.events.ResizeEvent;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;


        [Bindable]public var mediaServerUrl:String;
        [Bindable]public var videoFolder:String;
        [Bindable]public var filename:String;
        [Bindable]public var comments:String;


        private var ns:NetStream;
        private var nc:NetConnection;
        private var video:Video;
        private var meta:Object;

        private function ns_onMetaData(item:Object):void {
            trace("meta");
            meta = item;

            var vidAspectRatio:Number = item.width / item.height;
            var titleWindowAspectRatio:Number = vidContainer.width / vidContainer.height;

            // Resize Video object to same size as meta data.
            if ( vidAspectRatio < titleWindowAspectRatio ) // TitleWindow too wide
            {

                video.height = vidContainer.height;
                video.width = video.height * vidAspectRatio;
            } 
            else if ( vidAspectRatio > titleWindowAspectRatio )  // TitleWindow too tall
            {
                video.width = vidContainer.width;
                video.height = video.width / vidAspectRatio;
            } 
            else // TitleWindow and Video have same aspect ratio and fits just right
            {
                video.width = vidContainer.width;
                video.height = vidContainer.height;
            }

            // Resize UIComponent to same size as Video object.
            myVid.width = video.width;
            myVid.height = video.height;

        }

        private function fetch_rec():void {
            var nsClient:Object = {};
            nsClient.onMetaData = ns_onMetaData;

            nc = new NetConnection();
            nc.connect(null);
            ns = new NetStream(nc);
            ns.client = nsClient;

            video = new Video(myVid.width,myVid.height);
            video.attachNetStream(ns);
            video.smoothing=true;
            myVid.addChild(video);

            ns.play("../swf/barsandtone.flv");
        }

        protected function CloseWindow(event:CloseEvent):void
        {
            ns.close();
            nc.close();
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:HGroup id="vidContainer" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center" height="100%" width="100%" bottom="50" >
    <mx:VideoDisplay id="myVid" visible="true"
                     autoPlay="true" 
                     creationComplete="fetch_rec()"
                     playheadUpdate="progBar.setProgress(myVid.playheadTime,myVid.totalTime)"/>
</s:HGroup>

<mx:ProgressBar id="progBar" left="10" right="10" bottom="60" height="10" label="" mode="manual"/>
<s:Label x="10" bottom="30" text="Σχόλια:"/>

<s:Label x="10" bottom="10" text="{comments}"/>
</s:TitleWindow>
```

Comment: Let me explain you... I have a component which shows thumbnails of videos...when you click i have put a function launchPopUp which creates a calls a new window component i have made called VideoPopUp.mxml and i give its width and height to be in the launchPopUp as `win.width = this.width;` `win.height = this.height;` respectively..
Now inside VideoPopUp i have the videodisplay where i set the height to be 100% and width=100% but when i do the above when i set only one of these i dont see any property called scaledmode maybe its only in the VideoPlayer component...? What to do? any idea?

Comment: Try just setting width=100%, but remove the height property. If that doesn't work, can you post the code for VideoPopUp.mxml in your question?

Comment: I spent some time fiddling with your code and found a possible solution.  See the code I posted above.

Comment: i dont know but it seems not to work for me.. :S The code i use to call this popUp is shown above in the edit...maybe there is the problem..

Comment: no i dont get an error message but when my main app runs at full screen at my 15' laptop where my screen is wide the popup window width stretches it does not seem to maintain the aspect ratio... :/